# Jekyll on windows8 have UTF8 error

Tags: utf-8, jekyll

Thanks! I installed jekyll on windows9,but when I served jekyll on Chinese blog,it show utf8 error,but when i served jekyll on english-only blog,it works!
Here is my screenshot

Zepu@ZEPUXI /E/Github/utf8 (master)

```
$ jekyll serve

Configuration file: e:/Github/utf8/_config.yml

        Source: e:/Github/utf8
   Destination: e:/Github/utf8/_site
   Generating...
   Error reading file e:/Github/utf8/_posts/2015-04-11-jekyll_on_windows.md: invalid 
  byte sequence in UTF-8
  jekyll 2.4.0 | Error:  invalid byte sequence in UTF-8
```

This is served an english blog screenshot

```
$ jekyll serve
Configuration file: e:/Github/rifyll-master/rifyll-master/_config.yml
        Source: e:/Github/rifyll-master/rifyll-master
   Destination: e:/Github/rifyll-master/rifyll-master/_site
  Generating...
                done.
 Please add the following to your Gemfile to avoid polling for changes:
 gem 'wdm', '>= 0.1.0' if Gem.win_platform?
 Auto-regeneration: enabled for 'e:/Github/rifyll-master/rifyll-master'
 Configuration file: e:/Github/rifyll-master/rifyll-master/_config.yml
 Server address: http://0.0.0.0:4000/
 Server running... press ctrl-c to stop.
```

so my chinese blog _config.yml is here:

```
encoding: UTF-8

# Dependencies
markdown:            rdiscount
highlighter:         pygments


# Permalinks
#
# Use of `relative_permalinks` ensures post links from the index work
permalink:           pretty
relative_permalinks: true
```

HOW CAN I SOLVED THIS PROBLEM?THANKS!!!

Comment: i use ruby version is 2.0.0

Answer (score 0):

Can you check that your file `e:/Github/utf8/_posts/2015-04-11-jekyll_on_windows.md` doesn't have `BOM`

1. Go in your text editor our IDE setup an loock for file encoding. Be
   sure to select `utf-8` and `no BOM` (notepad ++ does this well).
2. Save your document
3. `Jekyll serve --trace`